# Regex PHP -- replace colors in a name -- but only if they are in colors and not part of company names

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a few possibilities for an input term:

1. "black and blue toy" (black and blue are colors) ==> "toy"
2. "silver spoon" (silver is a color) ==> "spoon"
3. "black and decker drill system" (notice, black is not a color -- it is part of a brand name - black and decker) ==> "black and decker drill system"
4. "red car" (red is a color) ==> "car"

What i want to do

- replace colors with "" -- but only if it is a color. So for #3 above i do not want black replaced since it is part of a brand. After "and " in 3 it is not a color so that i can infer that is part of a name instead.
- Now the question is how do i do it? :)

> ```
> $common_terms_to_replace_for_tag_search = array("green","blue","grey","gray","black","red","silver","maroon","violet","white");
> $term = str_replace($common_terms_to_replace_for_tag_search," ",$term);
> ```

However, above code only works for examples cases 1, 2, 4 - and not for 3. How do i update code update to work for cases such as 3 above? Thanks much!

Comment: If the brands are known, an oft-used hack is to tokenize them to something else, do the general replace, and the replace the token with the original string.

Comment: You can't. You would need a very extensive list of company names with colours in them and even then there would be situations where the colour can both be part of the name or a colour.

Comment: That's not something that you can do with regex's, what you _can_ do, though, is ensure you're not replacing part of a word (ie: ***red***irect -> `preg_replace('/\bred\b/i', '', 'redirect');` will not replace _"red"_). Tell us why you'd need to to this in the first place, perhaps the problem is best fixed elsewhere (X-Y problem...)

Comment: I think the basic thing is to: replace <color> alone, or <color> and <color>.. where color is part of the array to search/replace. In the case of black and decker (its <color> and decker) and should not replace. The feedback i am hearing is that maybe regex wont do what i am looking for here..

Comment: you cant't do this deterministically. how would you distinguish a brand name that can be part of a legal sentence?

Comment: you should try Natural Language Processing tools to identify the role of words on each sentence and identify colors used as adjectives rather than part of a noun.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest turning those colors to a list of regexes, and then run `preg_replace` like this:

```
<?php
   $string = 'black toshiba';
   $all_color_alternation = "\b(?:green|blue|gr[ea]y|black|red|silver|maroon|violet|white)\b";
   $common_terms_to_replace_for_tag_search = array(
      "/$all_color_alternation\\s+and\\s+$all_color_alternation/i",
      "/\\bblack(?=(?: and $all_color_alternation|\s+(?!and)))(?: and $all_color_alternation)?\\b/i",
      "/\\bblue(?=(?: and $all_color_alternation|\s+(?!and)))(?: and $all_color_alternation)?\\b/i",
      "/\\bgr[ea]y(?=(?: and $all_color_alternation|\s+(?!and)))(?: and $all_color_alternation)?\\b/i",
      "/\\bred(?=(?: and $all_color_alternation|\s+(?!and)))(?: and $all_color_alternation)?\\b/i",
      "/\\bsilver(?=(?: and $all_color_alternation|\s+(?!and)))(?: and $all_color_alternation)?\\b/i",
      "/\\bmaroon(?=(?: and $all_color_alternation|\s+(?!and)))(?: and $all_color_alternation)?\\b/i",
      "/\\bviolet(?=(?: and $all_color_alternation|\s+(?!and)))(?: and $all_color_alternation)?\\b/i",
      "/\\bwhite(?=(?: and $all_color_alternation|\s+(?!and)))(?: and $all_color_alternation)?\\b/i");
   $replacement = array('');
   echo preg_replace($common_terms_to_replace_for_tag_search, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

I added `i` ignore case option to also remove color names in both upper and lower cases.

The first regex will first remove all colors within `COLOR+and+COLOR` context.

See [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMeFBZTXR1Z1h0b00).

Output:

```
black and white apple         ==>  apple
black and decker drill system ==> black and decker drill system
black apple                   ==>  apple
gray and black toshiba        ==>  toshiba
```

Comment: This will change _"reduction"_ into _"uction"_, use word-boundaries

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: Not now, I added `\b` word boundaries :) However, it is a limited work-around, I agree. Regexes are not THAT smart.

Comment: Sure - but like you said it is only for known context. The *general* context is to: replace <color> alone, or <color> and <color>.. where color is part of the array to search/replace. In the case of black and decker (its <color> and decker) and should *not* replace. Anyway above can be modified to make this happen?

Comment: So, you want to set the condition like "if there is `and COLOR` after `COLOR`, remove all", **and** another condition: "if there is no `and` after `COLOR`, remove the `COLOR`". Correct?

Comment: great looks like that did the trick. Works for "Black and Decker".. will cricle back if there any issues i run into for other similar patterns of company names. thanks again!

Comment: Stribizhev - "gray and black toshiba" unfortunately is returning "gray and toshiba".. i was expecting "toshiba". Since <color> and <color> should be replaced.. possible bug in your code? I couldnt find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74962/discussion-between-chicagodude-and-stribizhev).