# Exclude word from matches

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex:

```
[ ]\d+|(?<=[^-'(a-zA-Z0-9\n])\d+
```

it matches `the 100`, I want to exclude `the 100` match.

I tried to add: `(?!the 100)` but no luck!

Is it possible?

Thanks

**edit**:

here is what I need:

```
the 100           => the 100
_123              => _
(1234             => (
.12345            => .
?!8               => ?!
hi 123            => hi 
?? 1234           => ?? 

(123-123)         => (123-123)
aaa123            => aaa123
A1234             => A1234
Z_L12345          => Z_L12345
..A8              => ..A8
aaa a123          => aaa a123
```

Comment: so what do you want to match?

Comment: please give your initial string or whatever in which you want to match and exclude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a negative condition `(?!\b100\b)` like this:

```
(?:[\( ](?!\b100\b)\d+|(?<=[^-'(a-zA-Z0-9\n])(?!\b100\b)\d+)$
```

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB9lQ4/1).

I have added `(` to your `[ ]` pattern in the beginning to match `1234` in `(1234`.

Comment: @Frank: Please provide a string you want to match, I will adjust the regex.

Comment: @web-nomad: lookbehind can be variable length if it contains an alternation of fixed length subpatterns `(?<=fixedLengthSubPattern|AnOtherFixedLengthSubPattern|etc.)`

Comment: @Frank: Is it what you are looking for: `(?:[\( ](?!\b100\b)\d+|(?<=[^-'(a-zA-Z0-9\n])(?!\b100\b)\d+)$` ? https://regex101.com/r/aB9lQ4/1

Comment: @stribizhev yes thanks. It's not related to the question but do you know a way to use an array as exclusions and include each element in the regex pattern to exclude them?

Comment: In PHP, you can use variables to build the regexes with arrays. It all depends where to exclude, and how. Please check this answer of mine - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564288/regex-php-replace-colors-in-a-name-but-only-if-they-are-in-colors-and-not/29564428#29564428 - it shows how to build alternation lists from array in regexes. To exclude, you just need the negative look-ahead that checks the input until some boundary.

Answer (score 0):

An other possible pattern:

```
~[ ]?(?<![^\W_])\d+\z(?<!the 100)~
```

pattern details:

```
~            # pattern delimiter
[ ]?         # optional space (to trim it at the end)
(?<![^\W_])  # a kind of word boundary that allows the underscore
\d+\z        # digits at the end of the string
(?<!the 100) # forbids "the 100" (not preceded by "the 100")
~
```